# Change default onChange event of Yii ListBox using AJAX (I need onClick instead)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, yii

I have this code for a `<select>` element:

```
    $htmlOptions = array(
        'size' => '20',
        'ajax' => array(
            'type' => 'POST', 
            'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl('/module/controller/updateajax'),
            'update' => '#info',
            'data' => array('id'=>'js:this.value')
        )
    );

    echo CHtml::listBox('list', array(), $dataProvider, $htmlOptions);
    <div id="info"></div>
```

This creates the next code at the bottom of the `body`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
  jQuery('body').on(
    'change',
    '#list',
    function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            'type':'POST','url':'/yii/app/module/controller/updateajax.html',
            'data':{'id':this.value},
            'cache':false,
            'success':function(html){jQuery("#info").html(html)}
        });
        return false;
    }
  );
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

All works fine. But I need `onClick` event instead `jQuery('body').on('change',...` for reasons of my UX. Does exists something like?:

```
    $htmlOptions = array(
        ...
        'ajax' => array(
            ...,
            'event'=>'onclick'
        )
    );
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this extra click handler to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    jQuery('body').on(
        'click',
        '#list',
        function () {
            $(this).trigger('change');
            return false;
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!... Yes, this works fine. But looks like an extra-work hack that cause decreasing performance. I wonder if the ajax request is executing two times: by the original `onChange` and by the `onClick` event that calls the first one.